# autoplay muted video background angular 5

Tags: html, angular, html5-video, angular5

I would like to add auto-play muted video at the top of the home page of my website, I am using angular 5.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only in HTML as well. Here is my working example:

```
<video [muted]="'muted'" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" playsinline id="video-start">
    <!-- Dynamic Content -->
    <source *ngIf="backgroundVideo?.Link?.Url" [src]="backgroundVideo.Link.Url" type="video/mp4">

    <!-- Default Content, displaying when dynamic content has a problem -->
    <source [src]="baseURL + '/SiteAssets/assets/videos/film_kpmg_home.mp4'" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Be careful about that, if you write only muted="muted" instead of [muted]="'muted'", autoplay could not work fine in an angular project.

And, for autoplay property, you need also to use 'playsinline' attribute for only mobile browsers. It makes no difference for desktop.

Answer (score 0):

you can write this code directly to your **component.ts** file

```
window.onload = function () {
var element = document.getElementById('video');
element.muted = "muted";}
```

this my html code..

```
<video  id="video"><source src="assets/images/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```